# How is result passed from $http to the .onsuccess function?

Tags: angularjs

How is result passed from the $http object to the unnamed function that is executed on success?

```
$http
    .success(function (result) {
        ...
})
```

I know that the result is passed via any variable name that i put into the function. It is typically called `result`. But how is this done? It seems like wizardry to me.

I would expect to have to write something like:

```
$http
    .success(function (result=$http.result) {
        ...
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to study how both **[Javascript Function Paramters](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)** and **[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** work.

The code that you pasted comes, I Think, from some AngularJS Application.

If my assumption is correct, **$http** is a service and doesn't have anyone **success** method.

The success method is present on $http methods:

```
//get, post, ecc...
$http.get(...).success()
```

By the way:

1. Javascript doesn't provide any way to match parameters, their order is always the order provided by the callee and the names that you use is just for you [(Don't confuse with the IOC that the DependencyInjection in AngularJS does)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). **EXAMPLE 1**

```js
function loggerCase1(log1, log2, log3, log4) {
  console.log('loggerCase1 => param-1:', log1);
  console.log('loggerCase1 => param-2:', log2);
  console.log('loggerCase1 => param-3:', log3);
  console.log('loggerCase1 => param-4:', log4);
  console.log('---------------------');
};

function loggerCase2(log4, log2, log1, log3) {
  console.log('loggerCase2 => param-1:', log4);
  console.log('loggerCase2 => param-2:', log2);
  console.log('loggerCase2 => param-3:', log1);
  console.log('loggerCase2 => param-4:', log3);
  console.log('---------------------');
};
function loggerCaseN() {
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log('loggerCaseN => param-' + (i + 1) + ': ', arguments[i]);
  }
  console.log('---------------------');
};


var logs = ['log1', 'log2', 'log3', 'log4'];

loggerCase1.apply(this, logs);
loggerCase2.apply(this, logs);
loggerCaseN.apply(this, logs);
```

If it's all clear about **function parameters** behaviour in javascript... you will know that isn't possibile to *say give me the first as the second* or something like that, also, the example that you pasted seems similar to **[default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)** (implemented in ES6, aka Javascript Harmony).

Let's go to the point 2:

2. In a simple promise chain (find on google or see the link above) you can pass a result to the next callback using return. **EXAMPLE2**

```js
angular
  .module('promisechainging', [])
  .run(function($q) {
  
    $q
      .when('Hello World')
      .then(function(greetings) {
          console.log('ring 1', greetings);

          return greetings;
      })
      .then(function(salut) {
          console.log('ring 2', salut);

          return salut;
      })
      .then(function(ciao) {
          console.log('ring 3', ciao);

          return { message: ciao };
      })
      .then(function(result) {
          console.log('ring 4', result.message);

          return result;
      })
    
      .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('THIS LOG NEVER HAPPENS BECAUSE THERE AREN\'T REJECTED PROMISES');

          return $q.reject(error);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        console.log('We Are At The END');
      })
  ;
  
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="promisechainging"></div>
```

### Basically is not important how parameters are named!

Comment: Do I need to write a parameter name at all?

Comment: You can try to edit the parameters name in the examples that I provided and see how nothing changes!

the order of the logs is always log1, log2, log3, log4 even if your parameter names are log4, log2, log1, log3

Comment: Thank you! There were many good answers to my questions, but yours is the one that helped me the most.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is using the promise mechanism which basically returns an object that let you know when the result is available or an error has been thrown.

When the ajax call returns, angular is calling the promise and providing the result as a parameter.

It's just like calling a regular function.

Answer (score 1):

`$http` allows you to perform async network operations and returns a promise object (you can read more about promises in Angular [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)).

The `success` and `error` methods were used to declare callbacks to what happens when the promise is resolved (when the request was successfully completed) or rejected (when there was an error at processing the request). I used the past tense since they are now deprecated and the desired way to handle these is using the `then` method of the promise object.

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Basically, the syntax is pretty much the same - the successCallbackFunction has the same signature as the method you were passing in the `success` method of your example.

But this is only the method signature. Your callback function parameters can be called however you want (`result`, `data` etc). All you have to keep in mind is that the first parameter in your callback function is going to be the data returned by your request.

Answer (score 1):

```
$http
    .success(function (result) {
        ...
})
```

`$http` will return a `Promise Object` which is nothing but a Javascript Object with `success` and different other functions.

So the statement immediately becomes like below as `$http` is evaluated,

```
(Promise Object)
    .success(function (result) {
        ...
})
```

The `success` function of promise will *save* this anonymous function to be called once the promise is *resolved*. We can manually resolve promises, but I guess http will do this for you here.

Once http request(AJAX) is successful angular will tell this Promise object to run this success function by *resolving* the Promise, somewhat like:

```
suceess: function(responseData){ //success of AJAX
    resolve(responseData); //this will pass the result to promise
}
```

Once `resolve` is called promise object has the *result* with it, it will then call the success function you passed initially with this value of result.

PS: This is a rough idea, I ave to look into Angular source to see their actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functions are also class objects.

When $http completes it will call either the success or fail function - they are objects so they can be passed around. When it does, it will provide the parameters.